# Christmas letter?

Tags: cipher

On Christmas,I received a letter, looking at the sender, I found nothing, except an 'anonymous'.
I didn't understand why, but as I kept reading, it finally dawned to me that this is a puzzle, and here it is.

> What ye may think of this, a puzzle! What ye need to figure out, a passcode. >Axcjcn kh 9 mrprcb..
> Vh oacnwm. Jb hqd vjh fnnu taxf cqnc cq b rb j yjiiun, R frau wxc odncqna rwc8xmdun hnd cx fqcc cqcb rb jkndc, unc’b bajac.
> I will give you a few sentence, and that's all you'Il need to figure out what you have to do to get the gift.. ;) good luck!
> "I'm something useful, untouchable, yet buyable. I am expensive, however l'm not sensitive, I feel nothing. I'm the 2nd generation, without DNA. What l'm worth? I go up and down. I'm short with 3 letters. But guess what? I'm useful! I power many of my kinds, my cost is at 4 digits, and without me, most of my kinds wouldn't even exist. I guess l'm pretty important then..."
> That's it! Figure what I am talking about...send me back a letter, and l'll give you one of it!

> Best of luck,

> Anonymous

Of course I want the gift!, so help me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you might be receiving some

> **ETHEREUM**

---

First step:

> The encrypted text is encrypted with ROT9 and can hence be decrypted with ROT17. It gives:
>
> 'Rotate by 9 digits.. My frtend. As yhu may weel krow thet th s is a pazzle, I wirl not fuether int8odule yeu to whtt thts is abeut, let’s srart.'

Second step:

> There are lots of spelling errors, but they seem to be intended. Lets see what the 'errors' say:
>
> 'THERE ARE 8 LETTER'
>
> This seems to give the length of the answer

---

So lets look at the riddle, to which the answer is

> **ETHEREUM**

---

I'm something useful, untouchable, yet buyable. I am expensive, however l'm not sensitive, I feel nothing.

> Ethereum is a cryptocurrency, which is expensive but not tangible, nor is it a living thing, making it not sensitive.

I'm the 2nd generation, without DNA. What l'm worth? I go up and down.

> Ethereum is known as the second generation cryptocurrency, with Bitcoin the first.  Cryptocurrencies are well known to be very volatile in price.

I'm short with 3 letters. But guess what? I'm useful!

> All cryptocurrencies have a 3 letter abbreviation, with ETH being Ethereum's.

I power many of my kinds, my cost is at 4 digits, and without me, most of my kinds wouldn't even exist. I guess l'm pretty important then...

> Ethereum can act as a platform for other cypto coins to work off. At this point in time, a single coin is currently valued at roughly $3774 or £2999, a 4 digit cost.

And the bonus clue

> ETHEREUM is 8 letters!

---

Seems like a pretty good Christmas present!!

Comment: Yessir! Great job, now I’ll get a 4 thousand coin, all thanks to you :)

Comment: But how can you send a letter back to "Anonymous" without address. If there was an address then it's technically not "Anonymous".

Comment: @WhatsUp an envelope can have a ‘return to’ address on it, and the persons names still unknown so are still anonymous